# Replace value in one column if another column is missing

Tags: python, pandas

**DATA**

I have a dataframe called data looks like following:

```
Name              ID
JAMES             252
STEPHEN           578
JOY               nan
ROGELIO           473
FACS              nan
CLIFFORD          793
```

```
data['Name'] is a column of strings, and data['ID'] has numeric values.
```

**GOAL**

I want to replace data['Name'] with missing value NaN whenever data['ID'] is missing, i.e. nan.

The result would be:

```
Name              ID
JAMES             252
STEPHEN           578
NaN               nan
ROGELIO           473
NaN               nan
CLIFFORD          793
```

I have searched online but similar answers are all about using fillna() which is not what I want. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: `df['Name'].where(df['ID'].notnull())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this method?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {'Name':['JAMES','STEPHEN','JOY','ROGELIO','FACS','CLIFFORD'],'ID':[252,578,np.nan,473,np.nan,793]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df.loc[df['ID'].isnull() , 'Name'] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       Name     ID
0     JAMES  252.0
1   STEPHEN  578.0
2       NaN    NaN
3   ROGELIO  473.0
4       NaN    NaN
5  CLIFFORD  793.0
```

If you wish to drop the NaN values, add the following:

```
df = df.dropna(how='any')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       Name     ID
0     JAMES  252.0
1   STEPHEN  578.0
3   ROGELIO  473.0
5  CLIFFORD  793.0
```

Edit: I did the other way around, now it's correct.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This works like a charm! The dropna() function is also very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use .loc function to find all the index's where `df['ID']` is null and set `df['NAME']` as np.nan there

```
import numpy as np

df.loc[df['ID'].isnull() , 'NAME'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This gives exactly what I need!

Comment: This does NOT work since having 'NAME' creates a new column with np.nan as a vector for it.

Comment: 'NAME' column is already there in the dataframe, why it would create new column?

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DataFrame.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) is perfect for this :

```
df.mask(df['ID'].isnull())
```

Output:

```
       Name     ID
0     JAMES  252.0
1   STEPHEN  578.0
2       NaN    NaN
3   ROGELIO  473.0
4       NaN    NaN
5  CLIFFORD  793.0
```